# Getting error while attempting to connect to H2 database in SpringBoot (sts4)

Tags: spring-boot

I am a beginner in SpringBoot. I cannot establish the connection to the H2 database and insert the data.
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springbootproject1</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-web1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-web1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-explorer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.security.user.name=username
spring.security.user.password=password
logging.level.org.springframework=info
management.info.env.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

The main class

```
@SpringBootApplication

//@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringbootWeb1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootWeb1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

The error is as follows when run in info mode.

```
2022-08-27 20:04:54.413  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.s.SpringbootWeb1Application          : Starting SpringbootWeb1Application using Java 1.8.0_251 on DESKTOP-6U5SNIB with PID 8632 (C:\Users\User\Downloads\springboot-web1\springboot-web1\target\classes started by User in C:\Users\User\Downloads\springboot-web1\springboot-web1)
2022-08-27 20:04:54.414  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.s.SpringbootWeb1Application          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-08-27 20:04:54.449  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-08-27 20:04:54.449  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-08-27 20:04:55.084  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-08-27 20:04:55.114  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 24 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-08-27 20:04:55.565  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-08-27 20:04:55.571  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-27 20:04:55.571  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-08-27 20:04:55.619  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-27 20:04:55.620  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1171 ms
2022-08-27 20:04:55.807  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-08-27 20:04:55.883  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-08-27 20:04:55.890  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:a58a1162-8ec8-498e-a310-1f2325e399e8'
2022-08-27 20:04:56.017  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-08-27 20:04:56.045  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
2022-08-27 20:04:56.123  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-08-27 20:04:56.182  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2022-08-27 20:04:56.500  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-08-27 20:04:56.506  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-27 20:04:56.564  WARN 8632 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-08-27 20:04:57.657  WARN 8632 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/User/Downloads/springboot-web1/springboot-web1/target/classes/data.sql]: create sequence user_details_seq start with 1 increment by 50 create table user_details ( id integer not null, birthDate timestamp, name varchar(255), primary key (id) ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create sequence user_details_seq start with 1 increment by 50 [*]create table user_details ( id integer not null, birthDate timestamp, name varchar(255), primary key (id) )"; SQL statement:
create sequence user_details_seq start with 1 increment by 50 create table user_details ( id integer not null, birthDate timestamp, name varchar(255), primary key (id) ) [42000-214]
2022-08-27 20:04:57.660  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-27 20:04:57.660  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2022-08-27 20:04:57.873  WARN 8632 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-214]
2022-08-27 20:04:57.873  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-08-27 20:04:57.875  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-08-27 20:04:57.876  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-08-27 20:04:57.888  INFO 8632 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-27 20:04:57.910 ERROR 8632 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/User/Downloads/springboot-web1/springboot-web1/target/classes/data.sql]: create sequence user_details_seq start with 1 increment by 50 create table user_details ( id integer not null, birthDate timestamp, name varchar(255), primary key (id) ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create sequence user_details_seq start with 1 increment by 50 [*]create table user_details ( id integer not null, birthDate timestamp, name varchar(255), primary key (id) )"; SQL statement:
create sequence user_details_seq start with 1 increment by 50 create table user_details ( id integer not null, birthDate timestamp, name varchar(255), primary key (id) ) [42000-214]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.springbootproject1.springbootweb1.SpringbootWeb1Application.main(SpringbootWeb1Application.java:14) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/User/Downloads/springboot-web1/springboot-web1/target/classes/data.sql]: create sequence user_details_seq start with 1 increment by 50 create table user_details ( id integer not null, birthDate timestamp, name varchar(255), primary key (id) ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create sequence user_details_seq start with 1 increment by 50 [*]create table user_details ( id integer not null, birthDate timestamp, name varchar(255), primary key (id) )"; SQL statement:
create sequence user_details_seq start with 1 increment by 50 create table user_details ( id integer not null, birthDate timestamp, name varchar(255), primary key (id) ) [42000-214]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:90) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyDataScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.initializeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create sequence user_details_seq start with 1 increment by 50 [*]create table user_details ( id integer not null, birthDate timestamp, name varchar(255), primary key (id) )"; SQL statement:
create sequence user_details_seq start with 1 increment by 50 create table user_details ( id integer not null, birthDate timestamp, name varchar(255), primary key (id) ) [42000-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:247) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:898) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:572) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:237) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:261) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Also, when I try to view H2 database using http://localhost:8080/h2-console , I get the error "This site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect."

Comment: Your SQL script not successfully executed and H2 database not startup because your application throw "Syntax error in SQL statement" when application startup.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data.sql` file not correctly executed. Because your file includes multiple sql statement. When I check from the error log, your file includes 2 statements:

```
create sequence user_details_seq start with 1 increment by 50; 

create table user_details ( id integer not null, birthDate timestamp, name varchar(255), primary key (id) );
```

Every statements must be separated `;` symbol.

Please try to separate each of your statements this way.